# How to return utf-8 string from c++ PHP module

Tags: php, encoding, utf-8, localization

I rewrite PHP LDAP module and build it from PHP's sources, MSVC 9. I have utf-8 encoded string here.

```
char *buffer;
```

Afterwards I call

```
zval *tmp2;
MAKE_STD_ZVAL(tmp2);
array_init(tmp2);
......
add_index_stringl(tmp2, i, buffer, strlen(buffer), 1)
```

And wow!

In PHP script I get windows-1252 encoded string !
windows-1252 is my local codepage. In this case I lose Russian symbols, I get "???" instead of it.

How can I force php not to reencode my data according to local settings ? I need utf-8 in my script.

P.S. I can change system code page to windows-1251, but it isn't an option for other languages.

Answer (score 0):

PHP won't re-encode a string. PHP treats any string you give it as simply a sequence of bytes. It will only alter the actual bytes if you ask it to.

You say you see "???" in place of Russian characters, which suggests - if they really were UTF-8 encoded to start with - that you're simply displaying them in your browser window wrongly.

I suggest you inspect the actual byte sequence to see if your string is what you put in. For example, if your string was "и" try printing it out with `urlencode` and you should see "%D0%B8" which are the two utf8-encoded bytes. If you see only one byte, then I think the problem is with your extension.

You can check in your browser window that a UTF-8 encoded string will display correctly, by simplying echoing the example above, either as `echo 'и'` if your editor supports UTF-8, or `echo "\xD0\xB8"` if it doesn't.

If you still see "???" then make sure you set the encoding of the page as UTF-8, both in the markup (meta tag) AND ensure the server isn't disagreeing with it in the `Content-Type` header, which should be `text/html; charset=utf-8`. It's a very common mistake to have the HTML document saying the encoding is UTF-8, but the server saying it's windows-1252. some browsers will let the server override.